# Image processing - editing and saving multiple images

Tags: image-processing

How can I apply a particular image function (such as ImageTrim) to an entire folder of images and then save/export those edited (trimmed) images to a new folder?

Comment: What have you tried?  This seems fairly straightfoward. Iterate with `Do` or `Scan`, use `Import`/`Export`, and look up the [file name manipulation functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/OperationsOnFileNames.html). for constructing the new file name from the old one.  When everything is working, parallelize with `ParallelDo`.

Comment: Thank you! will try that. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try like this: for version: 11.1

get your folder files:

```
   path = "C:\\Users\\sunny";
   SetDirectory[path]
   files = FileNames[]
```

lets create your files:

```
   im = Import["ExampleData/spikey.tiff"]
```

[image]

```
   files = {im, im, im, im};
```

then image trim entire folder of images:

```
 img=ImageTrim[files[[#]], {{30, 30}, {90, 90}}] & /@ Range[Length[files]]
```

[image]

Export files to folder named trim:

```
   Export["C:\\Users\\sunny\\Desktop\\trim\\" <> "new_" <> ToString[#] <> 
            ".png", img[[#]]] & /@ Range[Length@files]
```